# Giant rack adapters

Tags: rack

I'm looking for replacement inserts to mount a Panner Rack.

I'm not sure what the name or part no. is, but I've attached a photo of the parts on the left hand side of the frame. I've lost the pair on the right hand side of the frame & all RHS bolts, as well as a short bolt that runs along the top through hole between the inserts.

Can someone help with the name or ID of these parts, the bolts used and if possible a supplier for Australia?

The bike is a 2019 Fastroad SL-1. The Rack is a Topeak Super Tourist DX Disc.

The black stay on the left is the rack, which is mounted to the two adapters that I still have attached to the left hand side of the frame. They seem to act as an adapter between the frame's mount system and a generic rack.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the big black stay in shot already ?  Is that your mudguard ?

Comment: If its a Giant proprietary rack system, then you just need to find a bike shop that sells Giant bikes. They should be able to order replacements from Giant.

Comment: @Criggie the black stay is the rack, it's attached to the inserts that remain on the left hand side. I've lost the matching pair of inserts on the right hand side of the frame.

Answer (score 4):

For those that ended up at this post trying to work out how to attach a rack to a giant fastroad, try taking the adaptor that comes attached into the frame and flipping it over so the bolts face out. Took me a stupid amount of time to work out that what they were for.

[image: close-up picture of the bottom of the rear seat stay (upside down, with the dropout at the top of the picture) showing bolt holes on the rack adaptor]

Answer (score 3):

At first I wondered if these were "zerts" a part of the suspension damping, but no the [Giant specs page](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/au/fastroad-sl-1-2019)
confirms these are rack mount points.

> Easy to accessorise 
>   Smart-mount rack and fender system lets you customise the bike

So a googling for "giant smart-mount rack" shows that its a proprietary system, and looks something like this Giant branded "rack-it-metro-e" rack

[image]

So your options are to either buy the custom factory part, or modify a generic rack to fit, or somehow interface a generic rack to this frame.

It may be possible to fit your generic rack to where that big black stay is now, perhaps between elbow and frame.  Or you could remove the black plastic fillers and perhaps bolt your mudguard to that leaving the larger mount for the rack stays.

Comment: TBH that factory rack looks ugly with the long anteater nose down to the frame.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm looking to buy the black parts that are shown in the photo, they seem to act as an adapter between the frame and a generic rack. I haven't been able to find the part name to order it so far, I think that might be a good a starting point. I believe there are some differences between the picture with mudguards and my setup: I don't have mudguards, and the rack attaches to a mount around the bottom of the seat post.

Answer (score 3):

I know the thread is dead, but for those, who are still looking for a Giant part number:

Giant ToughRoad Smart Rack Mount Flat Cover Kit: 12818G90001A1

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for finding some new and relevant info.  No thread is truely dead as long as google+friends ranks Stackexchange so highly; people keep finding these posts in the future.